# Removing a jQuery event handler while inside the event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a `keydown` event handler that I attach to my document so I can watch the `keydown` event everywhere. However, after a condition is met, I want to be able to remove that and only that handler. How can I do this?

This is my current handler:

```
    $(document).keydown(function(event){
        console.log(event);

        var tag = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if(event.which = 27 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea'){    //escape has been pressed
            _dismissModal(modal_id);
        }
    });
```

I want to remove this `keydown` event handler after `_dismissModal` is called. How can I do this without removing all `keydown` event handlers?

Comment: did you try jqueries off() method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use jquery off() method. You also could put your keydown logic in to a separate function so you only can target that keydown action in your off method.

```
var mykeydownfunction= function(){
    console.log(event);

    var tag = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(event.which = 27 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea'){    //escape has been pressed
        _dismissModal(modal_id);
        $(this).off('keydown', mykeydownfunction);// $(this) is the document
    }
}  

 $(document).on('keydown', mykeydownfunction);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove the event handler.

```
$(document).on("keydown", function(event){
    console.log(event);

    var tag = event.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if(event.which = 27 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea'){    //escape has been pressed
        _dismissModal(modal_id);
        $(this).off("keydown");
    }
});
```

Comment: Will that remove all keydown event handlers or just mine?

Comment: I want to remove only mine.

Comment: Then @kasper Taeymans has provided you with your solution - just use a named function as opposed to an anonymous one.

Answer (score 3):

This has been answered already but using namespaces with removing events is really helpful and makes sure you don't cause any side effects.

```
// add click event with my.namespace as the namespace
$('element').on('click.my.namespace', function (e) {
    // do something
});

// remove my.namespace click event from element
$('element').off('click.my.namespace');
```

You can open up the dev console and look at the events of an element with

```
$._data($('element')[0], 'events');
```

Open up the Object and you will see a click array.  Expand your event and you will see the namespace actually shows up as

```
namespace.my
```

and not

```
my.namespace
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Search for Event names and namespaces for more info.

Answer (score 2):

When the condition is met, use [.off()](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
$(document).off('keydown');
```

Comment: Will that remove all keydown event handlers or just mine?

Comment: @Malfist - this will remove all keydown event handlers.

Comment: see my answer to only remove a specific keydown action. @Krishna: no worries mate :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use [**.off()**](http://api.jquery.com/off/)

```
 $(document).off('keydown');
```

Comment: Will that remove all keydown event handlers or just mine?

Comment: @Malfist, all events of that type (both direct and delegated) are removed from the elements (here document) in the jQuery set

Answer (score 0):

Just name that function to keep things inline.

```
$(document).keydown(function myhandler(e) { // <- see? "myhandler"!
    //do stuff blahblah
    $(document).off("keydown", null, myhandler)
});
```

P.S. Same thing without jquery:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function myhandler(event) {
    //blahblahblah do stuff
    document.removeEventListener("keydown", myhandler);
});
```